# SVG.js not working when bundled with ParcelJS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, bundler, parceljs

I am working with ParcelJS V2 and SVG.js. I am constantly getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: _svgDefault.default(...).size is not a function
```

which is referring to this line of code

```
let draw = SVG("#canvas").size(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
```

ParcelJS is trying to bundle the code for SVG.JS into my main `app.js` file.

Things I have tried

- Adding SVG.js from cdn as a script tag in my HTML `head`.
- Copying SVG.js code into a local file and exporting, then importing.
- Copying the entire SVG.js into my `app.js`.
- Installing ParcelJS with `npm` and then importing it.
- Instead of using a `div` to render SVG, I used `canvas` and upon inspecting elements, the `canvas` tag had some children `svg` tags but nothing rendered on the screen.

Parcel is trying to compile SVG.js which is probably causing the issue. Is there any way to fix this?